# How to insert the number of id in the neighbor column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with this structure:

```
+----+-------------------+
| id | identical_with_id |
+----+-------------------+
```

`id` is auto-increment and I need to insert in the this column `identical_with_id` exactly identical value with `id`'s value. How can I do that?

I want something like this:

```
+----+-------------------+
| id | identical_with_id |
+----+-------------------+
| 1  | 1                 |
| 2  | 2                 |
| 3  | 3                 |
+----+-------------------+
```

---

Note, in reality the table is also containing some other values for `identical_with_id` column, like this:

```
+----+-------------------+
| id | identical_with_id |
+----+-------------------+
| 1  | 1                 |    -- it is a question
| 2  | 1                 |    -- it is the answer of the above question
| 3  | 1                 |    -- it is the answer of the above question
| 4  | 4                 |    -- it is a question
| 5  | 4                 |    -- it is the answer of the above question
| 6  | 6                 |    -- it is a question
| 7  | 7                 |    -- it is a question
| 8  | 7                 |    -- it is the answer of the above question
| 9  | 7                 |    -- it is the answer of the above question
+----+-------------------+
```

Now I need to insert a question in the table. And I want to know how can I fill this column: `identical_with_id` ?

Comment: There is no reason why you would ever need to do this

Comment: How do you generate `id`? If `id` values are manualy inserted then you can simply do it with the initial insert : `Insert into table_name (id,identical_with_id) values (X,X)`  if `id` is generated by sequence than you can do it with after insert trigger.

Comment: @Strawberry I need to create a link between question and its answers ..

Comment: This is a **horibale** design.  create a table for Questions. Create a table for Answers. and Crreate a table that will link between them.

Comment: @Shafizadeh No you don't. You're confusing data storage with data retrieval. By convention, we use NULL for orphans.

Comment: According to me question should be in another table and you should have foreign question_id in answer table ,anyways according to your table next question will be id=10, with identical_with_id =10.I guess you can insert to the table with identical_with_id=NULL and then update with last_inserted_id to identical_with_id

Comment: @Strawberry Maybe using `NULL` could be fine in my case ..!

Comment: @SanalK This structure is the structure of stackoverflow .. So it should be fine `;-)`

Comment: @Strawberry Well, if I use `NULL`, fetching them will be hard ..! But now I can fetch them simply like this `WHERE  table.identical_with_id= :id`

Comment: @Shafizadeh It's safe to say that if you don't understand how to do this (and you're doing it in MySQL), you don't understand why StackOverflow does it. You're much better off splitting it into two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to update the table. You can do it in the single insert query like shown below.

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` VALUES(NULL, (SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'));
```

Although I don't see the point of doing so...

Comment: I don't know it works or not .. but yes I need something like this. I will check it out

Comment: Will this solution work all the time? Maybe between *executing that sub-query* and *inserting that row*, a new row *(another row)* inserts. Hum? is that possible?